# .htaccess remove subdirectory from URL but include sub-subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a local set up like this:

local.com/test/folder1/

How can I remove the 'test' directory from the URL but still include 'folder1' through .htaccess?  like this:

local.com/folder1/

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if test/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!test/)(.*)$ test/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!test/)` is negative lookahead to skip rewrite when request is already starting with `/test/`

Comment: cool, thanks.  When I type in local.com/folder1/  it works great but when i type in:

local.com/folder1  it goes to local.com/test/folder1/

anyway to prevent that from happening?

Comment: One last question. I have local.com/test2/  as a directory now it is saying it is 404 not found.  How can I only apply the rules you wrote to ONLY directory 'test'??